# Creating multiple directories using docker RUN

Tags: docker

When running the following in a terminal on my Linux machine:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/storage/{logs,framework,app}
```

It create the following directories:

```
/tmp/storage/app
/tmp/storage/framework
/tmp/storage/logs
```

While building using `RUN` in a Dockerfile results in a single directory called:

```
/tmp/storage/{logs,framework,app}
```

I know I could just create multiple RUN each with a `mkdir` pr directory but I'm curious to why the other command doesn't work and if there is a way of actually doing it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`RUN` commands use `/bin/sh`, while you are most likely using `/bin/bash` at the terminal.  To get the Bash behavior, use Bash:

```
RUN bash -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/storage/{logs,framework,app}'
```